# SharePoint List Forms in Visual Studio

Tags: list-form

I'm trying to attach custom aspx forms to a content type, in order to use them as New, Display and Edit item forms.
I must do this with Visual Studio 2010, since I have a Web Template, List Definition, Content Type definitions, etc..

Does anyone know the procedure to do this?

I found this link: http://www.sharemuch.com/2010/03/15/customizing-sharepoint-2010-item-forms-with-visual-studio-2010, but I can't understand how to create the item forms there, nor link them.

If no one knows the way, could at least anyone help me understand that post?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this tutorial is better in explaining custom content type forms:

http://sharepointmagazine.net/technical/development/customizing-the-user-experience-of-sharepoint-content-type-user-interface-part-4-of-6

It is written for Sharepoint 2007, but still applicable with SP2010 + Visual Studio 2010

This site is no-longer available.

Answer (score 0):

Also, be aware of the [ListFieldIterator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.webcontrols.listfielditerator.aspx) control as another way of displaying item details and fields.