# Create Custom New Edit and Display form for sharepoint list

Tags: list, custom

I am new to SharePoint and I have created several custom lists. I would like to use visual studio 2010 to create new EDIT/NEW/DISPLAY forms for this list. I can't seem to find anything on the internet explaining how to design these new forms with Visual Studio 2010. I would like for some guidance on how this can be done. I simply want to change the UI of the forms and make it look pretty using JQuery and that is the only purpose I have.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
</Fields>
<Views>
  <View BaseViewID="0" Type="HTML" MobileView="TRUE" TabularView="FALSE">
    <Toolbar Type="Standard" />
    <XslLink Default="TRUE">main.xsl</XslLink>
    <RowLimit Paged="TRUE">30</RowLimit>
    <ViewFields>
      <FieldRef Name="LinkTitleNoMenu"></FieldRef>
    </ViewFields>
    <Query>
      <OrderBy>
        <FieldRef Name="Modified" Ascending="FALSE"></FieldRef>
      </OrderBy>
    </Query>
    <ParameterBindings>
      <ParameterBinding Name="AddNewAnnouncement" Location="Resource(wss,addnewitem)" />
      <ParameterBinding Name="NoAnnouncements" Location="Resource(wss,noXinviewofY_LIST)" />
      <ParameterBinding Name="NoAnnouncementsHowTo" Location="Resource(wss,noXinviewofY_ONET_HOME)" />
    </ParameterBindings>
  </View>
  <View BaseViewID="1" Type="HTML" WebPartZoneID="Main" DisplayName="$Resources:core,objectiv_schema_mwsidcamlidC24;" DefaultView="TRUE" MobileView="TRUE" MobileDefaultView="TRUE" SetupPath="pages\viewpage.aspx" ImageUrl="/_layouts/images/generic.png" Url="AllItems.aspx">
    <Toolbar Type="Standard" />
    <XslLink Default="TRUE">main.xsl</XslLink>
    <RowLimit Paged="TRUE">30</RowLimit>
    <ViewFields>
      <FieldRef Name="Attachments"></FieldRef>
      <FieldRef Name="LinkTitle"></FieldRef>
    </ViewFields>
    <Query>
      <OrderBy>
        <FieldRef Name="ID"></FieldRef>
      </OrderBy>
    </Query>
    <ParameterBindings>
      <ParameterBinding Name="NoAnnouncements" Location="Resource(wss,noXinviewofY_LIST)" />
      <ParameterBinding Name="NoAnnouncementsHowTo" Location="Resource(wss,noXinviewofY_DEFAULT)" />
    </ParameterBindings>
  </View>
</Views>
<Forms>
  <Form Type="DisplayForm" Url="DispForm.aspx" SetupPath="pages\form.aspx" WebPartZoneID="Main" />
  <Form Type="EditForm" Url="EditForm.aspx" SetupPath="pages\form.aspx" WebPartZoneID="Main" />
  <Form Type="NewForm" Url="NewForm.aspx" SetupPath="pages\form.aspx" WebPartZoneID="Main" />
</Forms>
```

Comment: Have you seen http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/7417/sharepoint-list-forms-in-visual-studio ?

Comment: Yeah I actually came across this post several times and I am having a hard time trying to perform the same actions. I simply would like to create new forms for the custom list definition I created In VS2010. Are there any standard documentation explaining the correct "non-hack" way of creating forms.

Comment: To make it real simple. I would like a tutorial that can show me how to create a list definition with all views from within Visual Studio without copying and pasting generated code. I know there is a formal way on how to do custom lists and forms from vs2010 without "hacks"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are Two ways u set your application page as List Default New/Edit/Display Form.

1. Check This http://ikarstein.wordpress.com/2010/12/29/walkthrough-create-custom-sharepoint-2010-list-form-for-deployment-in-a-visual-studio-2010-project/
2. also in schema of your custom list definition add this after FieldRefs

   ```
    <XmlDocuments>
   <XmlDocument NamespaceURI="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/v3/contenttype/forms">
     <FormTemplates xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/v3/contenttype/forms">
       <Display>ListForm</Display>
       <Edit>ListForm</Edit>
       <New>ListForm</New>
     </FormTemplates>
   </XmlDocument>
   <XmlDocument NamespaceURI="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/v3/contenttype/forms/url">
     <FormUrls xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/v3/contenttype/forms/url">
       <Edit>HERE IS THE URL OF YOUR CUSTOM PAGE</Edit>            
     </FormUrls>
   </XmlDocument>
    </XmlDocuments>
   ```

Comment: That was all I needed one more question under the <FormTemplates> node do I specify just the name of the form. and then it uses the FormUrls tag to reference the actual form. Could you post an example of those tabs populated. I really appreciate your help and I will mark your answer as the answer because it answered my question.

Comment: Here is my list schema here I don't see how to implement your code.

Comment: see This http://screencast.com/t/Tr5shVtu5ZVv

Comment: Does that go into the Schema file. I see field references under the content type node. But in schema there is a <Fields> and a <ViewFields> node so when I add my content type to the schema should it have field references also. What about the <Forms> tag should this be deleted

Comment: Thank you once again you are really helping me grasp this I am new to sharepoint but not .NEt

Comment: You know what would be really good. Do you know where I can find a sample project download that has a custom list implementation with custom pages.

Comment: I figured it it's best to use rendering templates and webparts.

Comment: Hi thare is one article http://mstechsharing.blogspot.in/2012/05/create-workflow-with-custom-task-form_7581.html 
in this he just create task list with his own form for edit item

Comment: That was an awesome article

Answer (score 3):

```
  var list = SPContext.Current.Web.Lists[new Guid(Request.QueryString["list"])];
                var itemId = 0;
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.QueryString["id"]) == false)
                {
                    int.TryParse(Request.QueryString["id"], out itemId);
                }
                SPListItem listItem = null;
                if (itemId == 0)
                {
                    listItem = list.AddItem();
                }
                else
                {
                    listItem = list.GetItemById(itemId);
                }
String TaskTitle = Convert.ToString(txtTitle.Text);
            String TaskFrequency = ddlTaskFrequency.SelectedItem.Text;
 listItem["Title"] = TaskTitle;
 listItem["TaskFrequency"] = TaskFrequency;
 listItem.Update();
            Context.Response.Write("<script language='javascript'> window.frameElement.commitPopup();</script>");
            Context.Response.Flush();
            Context.Response.End();
```

If you are using same aspx page then in edit form you have to load like this.

```
private void LoadData()
        {
            var list = SPContext.Current.Web.Lists[new Guid(Request.QueryString["list"])];
            var itemId = 0;
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.QueryString["id"]) == false)
            {
                int.TryParse(Request.QueryString["id"], out itemId);
            }
            if (itemId != 0)
            {
                var listItem = list.GetItemById(itemId);
                ddlNotificationType.SelectedIndex = ddlNotificationType.Items.IndexOf(ddlNotificationType.Items.FindByText((listItem["NotificationType"] == null) ? string.Empty : listItem["NotificationType"].ToString()));
                txtTitle.Text = (listItem["Title"] == null) ? string.Empty : listItem["Title"].ToString();
                ddlTaskFrequency.SelectedIndex = ddlTaskFrequency.Items.IndexOf(ddlTaskFrequency.Items.FindByText((listItem["TaskFrequency"] == null) ? string.Empty : Convert.ToString(listItem["TaskFrequency"])));
}
```

and in your aspx page form load call this method

```
if (!Page.IsPostBack)


LoadData();           {
}
```

Comment: This so beautifully explained you have just unleashed some new capabilities that I needed so bad. Now I can easily create a master detail form for my list items. I have had a very hard time creating the master/detail type forms.

Answer (score 1):

Below is a beautiful step by step article posted. Kindly go through the same.

(http://ranaictiu-technicalblog.blogspot.in/2011/06/sharepoint-custom-addeditdisplay-form.html)

Thanks,
Sandy

Comment: This is great I ended up using Jquery but I will be able to get a lot more functionality this way. Is the SharePoint server Object model available to the aspx page and can you access the controls for each field.

Comment: Yes you can use share point object model to the aspx page.For example if you want to add the items which you have entered in aspx page to a list you can use th ebelow code.

Comment: i have posted the code above