# How to display fields horizontally in a New or Edit form in a Sharepoint list

Tags: custom-form

I'm build a sharepoint list and a form that will allow me to track projects and spend through the year. I would like to display the monthly spend input fields horizontally (across) rather than vertically. How can this be done?

Answer (score 1):

You could do this in a few different ways:

1. **InfoPath** - customizing or creating List forms in InfoPath gives you a lot more flexibility than the default SharePoint lists
2. **SharePoint Designer** - with SharePoint Designer you can edit the default "New" and "Edit" pages.

Comment: I'm using Designer. The way the form is set up it looks like a table. And I can't add consecutive fields within the same row/cell....

Answer (score 0):

There is also a third option, creating customized forms in Visual Studio: [Create Custom New Edit and Display form for sharepoint list](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/46489/create-custom-new-edit-and-display-form-for-sharepoint-list).