# Is there a way to programmatically choose an EditForm in an event receiver?

Tags: 2013, form, edit

In essence, the problem I face is this: two groups of users need to access the same document library. One group submits documents plus some metadata, the other vets the documents and edits the metadata, and eventually "approves" the whole lot. Some of the metadata is "approver-only".

I need to have a distinct edit form for each group. Is there some way that I can use, say, an ItemAdding event receiver to control who sees which form?

If not, is there an alternative I can use without a huge investment in time and effort?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend a simple approach. Use this guidance to change EditForm for the list: [Create Custom New Edit and Display form for sharepoint list](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/46489/create-custom-new-edit-and-display-form-for-sharepoint-list)

In newly created application page create two panels (asp:panel should do). One panel for one group, and another panel for second group. Both panels should be attributed as hidden. In Page_Load event add an if statement where you test current user's group membership and simply show the appropriate panel.

Comment: The edit form appears as a modal dialog. Does that make a difference?

Comment: No difference at all. I had an identical request from my customers and this is the way I implemented it.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can create a custom ListFieldIterator and set field visibility and editability via Reflection dynamaically (for example, based on the user's role) as described [in this post](http://pholpar.wordpress.com/2011/11/09/setting-form-field-visibility-and-editability-through-custom-list-field-iterators/). You can download the complete sample from [here](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/SharePoint-list-form-ef7d732b).